# How to create UV maps to a heavily meshed 3D human head in blender?

Tags: uv, sculpting, hair

I am new to blender and using 3.5 version. I am trying to add hair to a 3D head, which is meshed heavily. After adding empty hair property to the head, in modifiers section, it is showing that "Surface UV map not defined". I watched tutorials to create UV maps, but it's not helping with this level of mesh. Can anybody help me with this?

[image: 3D]

Comment: While you *should* retopo this if you want to do stuff like particle systems, to just create an ugly, functional UV map you can use Smart UV Unwrap

Comment: If you put the mesh in Edit mode, you could try the menu item "Mesh :: Clean Up :: Decimate" and slowly adjust the factor from 1.0 (no decimate) downward to perhaps 0.5 (50% less/merges vertices).  You can end up with a very acceptable mesh with a much lower file/memory requirement, and then a simpler UV.